# Creating bean of FileInputStream

Tags: java, excel, spring, fileinputstream

I need to write 3 different sheets in the same excel workbook in JAVA. I need to segregate this task to 3 different classes, each class should write one excel sheet in the same file. Now everytime at the end of a class, I need to flush the data to that particular sheet. Something like,

```
inputStream =new FileInputStream("FileName.xls");
wb_template = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
inputStream.close();
wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(wb_template);

//Logic here

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("FileName.xls");
workbook.write(out);
    wb.dispose();
    out.close();
```

and repeat this common part of opening and closing in another class for another sheet.

Now, as my class is annotated with `@Component` annotation, I simply can not create `FileOutputStream` with new in my classes as the sample code above.
So I need to create bean for them. So now my doubt is, how many beans do I need to create for each type. i.e `FileInputStream`, `SXSSFWorkbook` and `FileOutputStream` ? As I need to dispose workbook at end of every class and need to close `FileOutputStream` at end of every class, will single bean be sufficient ???

I am novice to this field. Any lead will be appreciated.

Comment: What gives you the impression you cannot create stuff in a class? The fact that you use Spring (or which ever DI framework) doesn't mean you have to use it for everything. It still is just java...

Comment: You don't need a bean for everything. When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. Just open and close the `FileInputStream` inside whatever method uses it.

Comment: @EJP, I did the same, but bean creation failed with error something like could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook

Comment: @EJP, Found my mistake, Simply created them with new, and they are working fine. "When all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail." Exactly said :D

Comment: @ M. Deinum Accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think input and output streams are good candidates for Spring beans. 
Much better and more intuitive candidates are your excel sheet writers:

```
interface ExcelSheetWriter {
    void writeOneSheet(String excelFileName);
}

@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean(name="sheet1Writer) ExcelWriter getSheet1Writer() {
        return new Sheet1Writer(); //implements ExcelWriter
    }
}

class ExcelDocumentWriter {
    @Autowired @Qualifier("sheet1Writer") ExcelWriter sheet1Writer;
    @Autowired @Qualifier("sheet2Writer") ExcelWriter sheet2Writer;
    @Autowired @Qualifier("sheet3Writer") ExcelWriter sheet3Writer;
    //... use them to write the entire document
}
```

Good spring beans don't change state after initialization.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a different point of view, but my question is at one point, I need to create objects of FileInputStream, FileOutputStream, and SXSSFWorkbook, that's where I am failing.

Comment: Do it inside the bean code, i.e. in the implementations of ExcelSheetWriter. Don't try to create beans of type FileInputStream since they make bad Spring beans

Comment: Understood the concepts. Thanks :)

Comment: Found the issues. Working fine now. Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome. You can still hide the code of creating SXSSFWorkbook inside a factory Spring bean, then you inject dependencies on this factory. I wouldn't go further than this.